# CouchDB document update date

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, couchdb, cloudant

When I query a document, I want to see the last updated date. Is this possible with couchDB? Or do I need to store that information when I update it?

I'm using cradle:

```
db.get('key-name-123', function (err, doc) {
  console.log(doc); // I need the updated date
});
```

Comment: You'll need to store it yourself. If you use an update handler, you can automatically append that bit of data, but it will not prohibit documents that bypass the update handler. You could use that in conjunction with a validation function to ensure that the `updated_at` field changes between revisions.